# Pushing into a vector of struct an element of that vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stl, containers

I've declared a struct like this:

```
struct Point{
    double x,y;
    Point(){}
    Point(double xx,double yy): x(xx),y(yy){}
};
```

And I'm trying to fill the vector like this:

```
vector<Point> s(1);
Point tmp(1,2);
s[0]=tmp;
s.push_back(s[0]);
```

Unfortunately, doing this gives me a wrong answer when I display the content of s[1], but  `s.push_back((Point)s[0])` leads to the expected answer (e.g. a copy of s[0]).

**What is the difference between
`s.push_back(s[0])` and `s.push_back((Point)s[0])` that explains this differennce ?**

Is there any auto type conversion or something going under the hood?

Comment: `s.push_back((Point[0]))` doesn't make sense, `Point` is a type.

Comment: What wrong/correct answer to what?

Comment: `vector<Point> s(2, Point(1, 2))` would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

`push_back` take argument by const reference (and an other overload by rvalue reference), so

```
s.push_back(s[0]);
```

uses lvalue-reference of the first element, but, `push_back` may reallocate if capacity is not large enough. And so the reference pulled from `s[0]` is left dangling, and no longer viable.

On the other side

```
s.push_back((Point)s[0]);
```

create a temporary, and then `s[0]` is no longer used, allowing to push a valid `Point` in the `vector`.

Comment: where in the post does OP use &s[0] ? What youre saying is true, but OP isnt doing that so your answer is AFAICT irrelevant.

Comment: @Borgleader its not that. I get it. `s[0]` is being passed by const-reference to `push_back`, but `push_back` can reallocate the sequence bed on a resize, leaving that *reference* dangling. I admit the closing sentence makes no apparent sense (I would hope this comment does).

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh i see, that makes sense now. I kept thinking that you couldnt pushback a T* into a vector of T even if you tried, and didn't see it also applied to references. Good catch.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sure, but the question is still an unanswerable mess.

Comment: @Jarod42: I would suggest explaining why adding the typecast actually fixes the issue? (Seeing as OP asked why the cast helped)

Comment: This problem was specifically addressed here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#526 -- `s.push_back(s[0])` is required to work, even if the implementation has to bend over backwards to make sure it does.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I was resizing the vector in my original code!

Comment: I'd be interested to know what is the proper way to make a copy of `s[0]`.